# Why is my CSS not being compiled in Laravel?

Tags: css, laravel

Apologies if this is a duplicate question. I simply had to ask this.

Last night after struggling for hours, I contacted one of my teachers after a compiling error regarding bootstrap. After she had taken a look with me and fixed the problems, everything worked fine.

Now, today when I wanted to continue working in my custom SCSS stylesheet I applied a green color to the body to test. It didn't work. However it did compile, no errors were thrown and it appeared in the app.css. What am I doing wrong...? I ran npm run dev and npm watch just to be sure. I also tried clearing the cache to no avail.

My app.css showing the applied changes:
[image]

My custom SCSS stylesheet where I added the test change:
[image]

My app.scss file where I import/use my custom stylesheet:
[image]

My webpage:
[image]

As you can see, the changes are compiled but not shown. I have also attempted to connect the stylesheet in the page itself but to no help either. Really frustrating. Please help if you know more about this!

Comment: Use the browser's inspector to see if the body has any other class applied that could overwrite this. For testing purposes try using `background-color: red !important`. And ... you can always change Bootstrap variables in `scss/_variables.scss`, there should be something like `$body-bg`

Comment: Yes you are correct. I did mean to put red there, I was still thinking about yesterday where I coloured the body green. My bad.

Comment: "Use the browser's inspector to see if the body has any other class applied that could overwrite this."

Not really. The body is simply  the body. And while what you say in regards to changing the initial variables set by the project; it overwrote (not sure if this is correct) the variable put by bootstrap (the grey-ish tint) no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found an answer which works for me, although I do not like the way I am going about this now.

Apparently all I had to do was run php artisan serve to open the file on a localhost port.

Why do I not like this? I spent a good 30 minutes setting up a custom url for easy navigation purposes. It all worked fine and somehow now I have to make that switch. I wish I could work around this.

While it does seem to initially solve the problem; it is not my preferred tactic.

Comment: How exactly did you serve your pages without `php artisan serve`? Do you have a different web server set up?

Comment: I loaded all my pages by configuring a visual studio code hosts file to add a virtual host, then configured a windows file to recognize the URL as an official localhost server

Answer (score 0):

it could be that you css is cached, it often happens with css and js files.
try adding version after the css import and keep incrementing that number everytime you change the css.

```
css/app.scss?v=6
```